# Does Glide cache the transformed image or the original one?

Tags: android, imageview, android-glide

I'm using `centerCrop()` with Glide.

```
Glide.with(yourFragment)
    .load(yourUrl)
    .centerCrop()
    .into(yourView);
```

When a `transformation` such as this is used, does `Glide` cache the final `bitmap` or will it continue to `cache` the original `image` and apply the transformation to it every time the `ImageView` is shown? Basically, I'm trying to understand how it works and determine if I need to write custom code to cache the final transformed image.

Comment: which version of glide you are using?

Comment: I'm using 4.9.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Glide cache the final bitmap or will it continue to cache the original
> image and apply the transformation to it every time the ImageView is
> shown?

In `Glide`, caches the original, full-resolution image and additionally smaller versions of that image. For example, if you request an image with 1000x1000 pixels, and your `ImageView` is 500x500 pixels, `Glide` will put both versions of the image in the cache.

In Gide, we have different `DiskCacheStrategy`. Based on this available strategy, we can decide the caching of images.

`DiskCacheStrategy.NONE` -> caches nothing

`DiskCacheStrategy.ALL` -> caches all versions of the image

`DiskCacheStrategy.DATA` -> caches only the original full-resolution image.

`DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE` -> caches only the final image, after reducing the resolution (and possibly transformations)

`DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC` -> intelligently choose a cache strategy based on the resource (default behavior of Glide 4.x)

If you have an image that you know you'll manipulate often and make a bunch of different versions of it, it makes sense to only cache the original resolution. Thus, we'd tell `Glide` to only keep the original.

```
GlideApp  
    .with(context)
      .load(yourUrl)
      .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA)
      .into(imageView);
```

For more info on this, please check Glide [documentation](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-caching-basics)

Comment: Thanks. In my case, I only need one version of the image (the final transformation), so I will then use `RESOURCE`.